# Foursquare trending api with category filter

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm using the foursquare api (https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/trending) but I want to  get it filtered by category.
I tryed to use as the search api (parameter categoryId) and it didn't work.

can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't currently support filtering by category ID on our venues/trending endpoint.

Your best bet is to just call the trending endpoint with the maximum limit (50 venues), and then filter out the venues that don't have the desired category ID on the client-side.

Or, depending on what exactly you're trying to do with your application, you could use the venues/search endpoint (with intent=browse and the category ID filter), and simply re-rank the results based on the number of people in "hereNow".

Comment: Thanks! I'll do the search and re-rank myself!

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter option `category` for [`venues/trending`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/trending) in the current API version. You can query up to 50 trending nearby venues and filter the results yourself. The issue has also been discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/foursquare-api/Y8vcRL3MDa8).